# zIndex issues between two ASPxDockPanel

Tags: devexpress, z-index, dockpanel, aspxcombobox

I have two ASPxDockPanels in the same ASPxDockZone (vertical). The first panel has an ASPxCombobox with a dropdownlist that should go over the second panel.
However the dropdownlist is just rendered behind the second panel.

First panel has a z-index of 12000 while the second has a z-index of 12002 which explain the issue, so I tried to apply a CssClass property at each panels as suggested on [devexpress website](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q365005.aspx) but it still didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help, TheRainFall.

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issue?

Comment: Well, I tried here since I already had an account. I'll have to ask the company account on devexpress website (or make one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had my answer from DevXpress support.

It is related to [IE z-index bug](http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html) (IE7). Since I'm using IIS 6, the basic compatibility mode seems to be set on IE7 although users are using IE8.